# Automated GUI Testing of GIS Application

Tags: gis, automated-tests, gui-testing

I'm working as a part-time developer on a GIS application project and my project manager wants to me to do automated testing of project. I tried looking for solutions that can be helpful.

I found EggPlant -

http://youtu.be/M8-8UkKSGG8

But from this video it seems that it is doing pixel by pixel matching of snap shots took from Google Maps.

Can anyone please help me with Automated GUI testing of GIS application, what tools can be used and if possible point me to some open source tools ( We are kinda short of funds ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

AB,

eggPlant is a complete GUI driven test tool. drop us a note on info@testplant.com and we will be happy to answer your specific queries.

This are some more videos for your reference - 
Testing Based on Changing Conditions - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlXkSmLg1rM

eggPlant UAV testing -http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcoIB4dZU0k&feature=related

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I was wondering whether egg-plant supports applications that are deployed on multi-touch based devices like Microsoft Surface, Evoluce tables etc. I'm more interested in testing applications developed using Microsoft .net framework and WPF applications.

Comment: Another thing that I figured out is pixel by pixel mapping. I posted a video link where eggplant was testing Google Maps, apparently if my base map is changed (obviously which will whenever Google decides to update images on its servers) then it will cause breaking of all those tests, isn't it ?